# Meaning of a Threaded Program Specification

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, stream

I am supposed to implement a multithreaded application, but I have never one done before. I've found some good tutorials and am beginning to get the jist of multithreading. However, I've been given an assignment for a threaded application, and I have no idea what they're asking for:

> Implement a multithreaded application in the following manner: 5 reader threads read from 5 character data streams convert data to upper case and pass the converted data to 2 writer threads.

Can anyone explain to me what they mean by that? Should I be reading from 5 files and writing to two files? I really just don't understand their terminology.

Comment: So that's what a TPS Report really is. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that sounds like a reasonable interpretation for the assignment, and it makes sense to me (as an academic exercise).

Open 5 files, have 5 threads reading those files, send the data to some 'synchronized' store, and then have two other threads reading from that store (synchronized), and each writing the data to their output file.

Hints: Think queues, concurrency, synchronization, and threads.

Comment: Thanks, that actually helps a lot. I used the Java and C++ tag because I wasn't sure which of those two languages I would write the program using. I'm leaning towards C++, if anyone is interested.

Comment: Don't mix learning a language with learning multithreaded programming, use the one you are more familiar with. In case you're also a beginner in programming, I'd tend toward Java because it has the more comprehensive standard library surrounding the core language.